# react component state does not reset on subsequent call for same component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, refluxjs

So my Component looks something like this as mentioned below.
When the component is rendered for the first time, it sets the state. But for the 2nd call, the props hold new data but it never sets the state.Instead, the state has previous data.Not sure what is making the behaviour.The state I am interested in is 'data'

```
class MuiTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      order: 'asc',
      orderBy: this.props.columnData[0].id,
      selected: this.props.defaultAllSelect !== undefined && this.props.defaultAllSelect ? this.props.data.map(d=> d[this.props.uniqueKey]) : [],
      data: this.props.isSortable ? this.props.data.sort((a, b) => (a[this.props.columnData[0].id] < b[this.props.columnData[0].id] ? -1 : 1)) : this.props.data,
      page: 0,
      rowsPerPage: this.props.rowsPerPage,
      uniqueKey: this.props.uniqueKey
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to implement componentWillReceivedProps(nextProps) method and use this.setState(); to update your state.

This may help you: [React lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for directing me here. This solution actually helped and my component is working now.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal as this is the constructor method.
You should read the Component lifecycle methods, [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

For the update part of the lifecycle, it goes:

1. componentWillReceiveProps()
2. shouldComponentUpdate()
3. componentWillUpdate()
4. render()
5. componentDidUpdate()

Comment: Thanks for that! Sometimes it's all about not knowing the basics.